# EaselJS: Draw images independent of Container zIndex

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I have 2 containers, A which contains bitmaps A1 and A2; and container B which contains B1 and B2.

I want to draw them on the canvas in this order: A1, B1, A2, B2.

WHILE still having A1,A2 in A and B1,B2 in B because all the logic is built that way.

Is it possible to do it with built-in EaselJS functionalities?

The only way I found so far is to manually calculate absolute position and draw them with the conventional ctx.drawImage but it's slow and messy.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. You should change the logic in order to draw a shape or another before or later and, eventually, use setChildeIndex in order to reorder them

Comment: You can use the `draw()` method on any displayObject to manually draw it to a canvas context. This gives you the ability to use EaselJS display classes like Bitmap/Graphics/etc _without_ a stage. http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#method_draw